# How to get a string hash

Tags: .net, hash

Ihave created this function to return the string hash. but its not working;

//call 
Console.WriteLine(getHashCode("test"));

```
    static String getHashCode(String input)
    {
        int HashCode = input.GetHashCode();
        Console.WriteLine("{1:X8}", input, HashCode);
        return("{1:X8}", input, HashCode);
    }
```

Comment: When you say it's not working ... what are the expected and actual results that don't match ?

Comment: no, Console output is = EAE38E77 en the return = -{1:X8}

Comment: because the pattern '{1:X8}' is used for 'string.Format' function, and 'Console.WriteLine' will call it background. So, when you return data, you must call 'string.Format'.

Comment: Please note that calling `string.GetHashCode` is not guaranteed to return the same value between different versions of the .Net framework or between the same version of the framework but different architectures. It is not stable, and should be taken into consideration if the value is being stored and recomputed at a later date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use MD5CryptoServiceProvider to computeHash().

Comment: Now, I think your code should like: static String getHashCode(String input) { int HashCode = input.GetHashCode(); Console.WriteLine("{1}:{2:X8}", input, HashCode); return string.Format("{1:X8}", HashCode); }

Answer (score 2):

```
static String getHashCode(String input)
{
    string HashCode = String.Format("{0:X8}", input.GetHashCode());
    Console.WriteLine("{1}", input, HashCode);
    return HashCode;
}
```

There you go.

Comment: Your WriteLine call is pretty odd... you're passing a format string that ignores one of the parameters. And why bother with a format string, when all it's got is a single placeholder? You could simplify that to `Console.WriteLine(HashCode);`

Comment: True; I pretty much took OP's code and modified it to make it work. There's no reason why it can't be simplified by that change, though.